# How to flow context in Twitter Future in java

Tags: java, twitter, future, continuations

Using Twitter `Future` in Java how can I have the context in one created `Future` available down a chain of `map`s?

I've tried the following using `Contexts.local()`:

```
LocalContext.Key<String> key = Contexts.local().newKey();
Contexts.local().let(key, "SomeValue", func(() -> {
    System.out.println("inside let binding " + Contexts.local().get(key));
    return FuturePools.unboundedPool().apply(() -> {
        System.out.println("inside let binding but in other thread " + Contexts.local().get(key));
        return "initial future";
    });
})).map(v -> {
    // How to get the context here? The line below prints None
    System.out.println("outside let binding " + Contexts.local().get(key));
    return "mapped future";
});
```

Unfortunately the set value is no longer available in the lambda pased to the `map`. What do I do to have it available there too? And how do I do this in Java?

In e.g. a Twitter `Promise` the `map` implementation does a `Local.save()` but I don't see a way to add values to `Local`.